# How to make the scoreboard appear?

Tags: battlefield-4

So I got the new Battlefield game and in BF3 you pressed the back button to make the "Scoreboard" appear. But now the battle log appears instead. Is there a new button to make the scoreboard appear or can you not see your score till you finish the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hold the Start/Option button to show the scoreboard on consoles. On the PC, you can still find scoreboard by holding <kbd>TAB</kbd> (default).

> **You've buried the scoreboard in favor of making Battlelog easily accessible via the back button** [...] **What was the thinking behind this change?**
>
> [...] The score board is still available quickly by holding the Start/Option button. -- [source](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2013/10/27/dice-discusses-changes-coming-to-battlefield-4-console-controls.aspx)

Comment: It is kind of weird, I didn't even have to look for the scoreboard. I'm so used to pressing tab to get the scoreboard in most games, that I didn't even think it could be different in other games :p

Comment: @Lyrion it's tab for most PC games, but there's no tab on controllers, hence the question.